# FBSDKLoginManager() Dismiss .web view programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

I have a FBSDK login webview, I can dismiss it using the buttons with the app and completing social share task.

I'm trying to implement an app wide function that will remove it if no touches are detected after three minutes, when popping back to the home view controller the FB login view is still visible.

How do I programmatically dismiss it without user interaction.

```
var loginView:FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()

loginView.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehavior.web

loginView.logIn(withPublishPermissions: ["publish_actions"]){    (loginResult: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult?, error: Error?) in

    if error != nil
                   ...
```

How do I dismiss the FBSDKLoginBehavior.web programmatically if no user is there to cancel this login process.

Comment: Its automatically dismiss after successfully completion block.

Comment: @KiritModi I get that and it works for me, but say if the user doesn't log in.

How can I make it dismiss, without user input. Think kiosk app and user walks away without logging in, but the login view is still visible.

Comment: There is already cancel Button in WebView. or You are added Gesture on Webview so user touch on the Webview outSide of textfield or button. then remove webview.

Comment: The whole point is there is no user, I'm trying to remove the view if there is no user input.

Comment: Yes You remove from superView.

Comment: How tho?, loginView doesn't appear to have any methods that remove the view.  loginView.logOut doesn't work - and I didn't expect it to. 

I can't tag it and cycle through subviews, having a look at loginView it appears to be NSObject.

Sorry just seen what you said about removing from superview I've tried it doesn't seem to work, I'll update my example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124259/discussion-between-magrafear-and-kirit-modi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't found how to get modal window reference. But, you can use FBSDKLoginBehavior.browser and dismiss it:

In this sample Facebook login view will dismissed after 10 sec:

> ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit
import FBSDKLoginKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {

func loginButtonTouchUpInside(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    loginManager.logIn(withReadPermissions: self.readPermissions, from: self) { (result, error) in
        NSLog("login window dismissed")
    }
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .utility).async {
        sleep(10)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if let presentedViewController = self.presentedViewController {
                presentedViewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }
}

var loginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
let readPermissions =  ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends","user_birthday"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    loginManager.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehavior.browser
    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 100, height: 20))
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.blue, for: .normal)
    button.setTitle("Login", for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.loginButtonTouchUpInside(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    view.addSubview(button)
}
}
```